# How to use gcloud commands programmatically via - Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is there an option to use gcloud commands programmatically via - Java?
I see not all of the google provided libraries have all the functionalities that are present as part of gcloud command.

Comment: were you able to seolve it? I tried using runtime api to submit spark job but getting following error:ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.spark) ALREADY_EXISTS: Already exists: Failed to submit job: Job projects/my_bucket/regions/us-XXX/jobs/job-36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh :-(

You're correct but there's a better solution.

Please see this explanation:
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained

I discourage you from shelling out to calling the gcloud commands from Java to solve your problem *and* from attempting to make the calls directly.

In summary:

All of Google's services are available for all of the supported languages using the older client libraries called the API Client Libraries. The API Client Libraries are machine-generated and mostly guaranteed to perfectly reflect the underlying services:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/

For Google Cloud Platform, a newer (better) set of client libraries is available but, these have required hand-coding. It's not a good excuse but, because of this, these libraries have lagged their underlying services. The lag includes some services not being available in some languages, some methods of some services not being available etc.
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries

So, this creates a few challenges but...

If you require one set of libraries for everything, go API Client Libraries

Otherwise:

1. If the Cloud Client Library is available, use it.
2. If the Cloud Client Library is not available, use the API Client Library.

Comment: For one of my usecase, i feel it is not present in Cloud client library and also not present in the API client library. I was looking for a way to stop the GCP dataflow job. The gcloud command provides one. But I couldn't find an option for that in the library for that. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/dataflow/v1b3

Comment: Is it a secret? :-)

Comment: My bad. I ended up finding it. It was under dataflow.projects.jobs.update :-) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

url :

cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers

I found below description

"You can only use this feature through the Google Cloud Platform Console or the gcloud command-line tool, not the API."

here its not possible using api but only possible use gcloud command line.
so  using gcloud command from java is still issue.